# Tech thriller novel with brain-linking, set in circa-2000 Boston area

Tags: story-identification, books, cyberpunk

I’m trying to track down the title of a book I bought in about 2000.

The plot followed the “hacker-adjacent technology worker stumbles into someone’s plan to transform humanity” archetype, with the plan involving transcendence achieved through linking peoples’ brains together, possibly through the use of "nanotech".

A notable feature of the book was its setting in suburban Boston, and in particular around the mill building in Maynard that had previously housed the Digital Equipment Corporation headquarters.

The author was selling the book (and others) from a stand set up in a university student center. The book was paperback, and was likely self-published. I think the title was a single word that evoked the neuroscience and/or transcendence themes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_in_fiction

Comment: Playing around with other search terms, I've just found a very strong candidate, "Acts of the Apostles" by John Sundman. (Search term that worked was <sci-fi "DEC mill">, which turned up a goodreads review of a reworked version of the text by the same author.) I'll self-answer when I've had a chance to read the book.